# scaffold in subsonic

Tags: subsonic

Hey all i am using SubSonic 2.1 Version, how to access the scaffold control in our project.
Pls help me with code.

Regards

Kishore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup all the Subsonic stuff (like the configuration etc.). In you page register controls:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="SubSonic" Namespace="SubSonic" TagPrefix="subsonic" %>
```

Here is simplest way to use scaffold:

```
<subsonic:Scaffold ID="Scaffold1" runat="server" TableName="Table_Name">
</subsonic:Scaffold>
```